# Log view hierarchy of third party app in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiview

Is there any way to log out the entire view hierarchy in iOS?
Not just recursive description of my app's views.

Specifically, I want to log view hierarchy of third party app downloaded from the App Store.

Comment: Can you jailbreak the device? I've utilized this approach for reverse engineering the view hierarchy/logic of apps by patching them at runtime using MobileSubstrate.

Comment: @H2CO3, sure I can do it. Is it hard to use 'MobileSubstrate'? Where can I find some info how to actually use it to extract view hierarchy?

Comment: It's not hard to use it. What you want to do is override one of the early initialization methods of the app, then dump `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] recursiveDescription]`.